# No External Storage available Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-sd, storage

My galaxy s2 was in bootloop ,  I have installed cyanogen mod 10 on it . Now I can`t see any files on my storage , when I enter camera or gallery it writes "no external storage available" . And the file manager doesnt show it too . But when I enter to that storage from recovery it shows all files . What can I do?

Comment: That sounds like a configuration problem with your custom ROM.

Comment: It is official CM10 , I have tried official CM11 and unofficial CM12 , hazy rom I have tried too all those roms show me the same error.